# Does "Hues of the Violet Garden" feature any change if the player never met a character involved in the event before?

Tags: genshin-impact

The 2.6 event "Hues of the Violet Garden" has quite odd requirements:

> - Reach Adventure Rank 30 or above
> - Complete the "Ritou Escape Plan" part of the Archon Quest: "Chapter II: Act I - The Immovable God and the Eternal Euthymia"
>
> To best enjoy the event, complete these Story Quests first:
>
> - Kamisato Ayato's Story Quest "Cypressus Custos Chapter: Act I - The Firmiana Leaf Falls"
> - Raiden Shogun's Story Quest "Imperatrix Umbrosa Chapter: Act II - Transient Dreams"
> - Sangonomiya Kokomi's Story Quest "Dracaena Somnolenta Chapter: Act I - Warriors' Dreams Like Spring Grass Renewing"
> - **If the player has not completed Kamisato Ayato, Raiden Shogun, and Sangonomiya Kokomi's Story Quests, they can enter the event through "Quick Start."**

The event unlocks only when all the above requirements are met.

If a player has not yet played the three story quests mentioned in the notice, they can use a "quick start" feature to play the event as if they had - in this case the event is exactly the same and obviously the plot will reference events they may not yet have experienced. For example,

> the event takes place after the travel decree has been revoked and that only happens after the player completes the second act of Raiden/Ei story quest.

I was trying to make sense of the quest dependencies.

In order to play Raiden Shogun's Story Quest "Imperatrix Umbrosa Chapter: Act II - Transient Dreams" one must have played Act I before. To play Act I you must complete the Inazuma story arc, and to complete Inazuma you are forced to play the first acts of both the Ayaka and Yoimia Story Quests. This means that fulfilling the Raiden Story Quest Act II requirements means that the player has met Kokomi, Ayaka and Yoimiya in the game.
Obviously, the Kamisato Ayato's Story Quest requirements means that you will have met Ayato. Since you are in Inazuma, you must have completed the Mondstadt story arc, and thus you have met Jean and Venti, and at the very least heard rumors about Albedo. You also must have met Kazuha in the story before, in order to reach Inazuma in the first place.
So, basically everyone who was shown at the event in the version trailer to be covered.

Yet there is someone else...

[image: Screenshot from the game introducing the NPC Klee during the Hues of the Violet Garden feature]

Klee, also known as "What do you mean by 'Mihoyo favorite', surely someone else has gotten pictures in their books", "Where is the kimono skin she had in that promo image?" and "Kokomi #1 enemy".

Because of this inclusion, I would have expected that the event also required that the player completed the Trifolium Story Quest Act I chapter but it does not, meaning that the player may have never played the quest that introduces Klee in the first place.

For that reason I am wondering if the game in any way acknowledges the fact that, technically, the Traveler may never have met Klee face-to-face before, or if it simply goes on as normal with Klee behaving like the "Traveler's self adopted lil' sister", with no previous plot explanation or anything.

I have found clues that seem to indicate that never meeting Klee before at least triggers a prompt when she first appears (like any new introduced character does):

[image: Description of the NPC Klee as can be seen in-game]

But does any other dialogue or scene get altered beside that?

And what about Xingqiu and Chongyun, who, based on the trailer, should also appear at the festival at some point?

Answer (score 5):

### Of Klee

*Despite the fact that the event is not in the game anymore, people at the honeyhunterworld database keep full dumps of all the in-game dialogue (based on datamining).*

I was therefore able to confirm that no alternate version of the Klee arrival scene exist.

[image: Dialogue data dump - The Strange Tale of Suikou's Tipsy Tincture]

For added reference we can compare to the older event Unreconciled Stars: when the Traveler meets Mona during the quest The Crisis Deepens two version of the scene exist: one used if the player never meet Mona before and one if they did (having played her story act before the event).

[image: Meeting Mona in Unreconciled Stars]

Mona story quest has similar switches in place:

- If the player has played Unreconciled Stars before she will remember him
  [image: Mona remembering the Traveler if they meet first in Unreconciled Stars]
- If they never meet before she will tell the Traveler her name
  [image: Mona if she never meet the Traveler before]

Based on the fact that Klee arrival during "Hues of the Violet Garden" has only one version, I think it is safe to assume that the characters bio cards are the only possible difference in the event (you get cards only if you never meet the character before).

"Hues of the Violet Garden" was the first event to introduce the "quick start" feature. This was probably an attempt at simplifying the quests dependency chain by avoiding the need to have alternate versions of a scene if a player didn't play a specific quest before. Instead of trying to compensate for every possible outcome  they added a disclaimer that some of the event scenes won't make sense if played "out of order" by using the "quick start" option to skip dependencies.

In this specific case I think someone made the mistake to consider Razor story quest act 1 (a dependency for "We Will Be Reunited" which in turn is required by Chapter II: Act I - The Immovable God and the Eternal Euthymia) as the first appearance of Klee, but that is not true. While Razor references her, the Traveler won't know who "the red burny girl" is until they meet Klee in her story act.
It is also worth noticing that the player may never have personally meet Albedo either, but at least in that case you could argue they may know him by "fame alone" since he is mentioned multiple times by other characters an therefore him and the traveler meeting "off-screen" is quite plausible.

### Of Xingqiu

This seems a little more obscure. The event does not contain any alternate scene for Xingqiu  either, so it must assume the Traveler meet him before.

I am trying to find some hidden requirements that would force the player to have completed Xingqiu story quest. Both "Yae Publishing House's Invitation" and "The Crane Returns on the Wind" quest seems to just assume that the player MUST have meet Xingqiu before. I therefore think that there may be a dependency on Xingqiu Story Quest Act 1 hidden somewhere along the Liyue story arc, but I can point out where... I will update this answer if I can find further info, maybe the Archon quest forced you to visit the book store thus triggering Xingqiu Story quest in the process.